# Interpreting Array.forEach.apply results

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

In my browser console, I typed the following:

```
Array.forEach.apply(null,['a','b','c'])
```

The response was:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function
> at String.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at <anonymous>
> ```

I'm not quite sure what I thought would happen, but it wasn't this.  Also:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.apply(null,['a','b','c']);
```

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined
> at forEach (<anonymous>)
> at <anonymous>
> ```

I feel like understanding this would help expand my wisdom of JS.  Any sage JS developers know this one?

Additionally:

```
['a','b','c'].forEach.apply((function(a,b){return b;}),['a','b','c'])
```

The response was:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
> at String.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at <anonymous>
> ```

Comment: Why are you using `.forEach.apply` in the first place instead of `.forEach()` directly on the array?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `apply`? The first argument must be the `this` object, i.e. for array methods this should be the array to apply the method on.

Answer (score 1):

[Look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) at what `forEach` is supposed to receive as the arguments.

> ```
> arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
> ```

Then look at what you passing it with `apply`:

> ```
> Array.forEach.apply(null,['a','b','c'])
> ```

So:

- the `this` value (`arr`,which should be an array) is `null`.
- the first argument (`callback`, which should be a function) is the string `a'`
- the second and third arguments (which shouldn't exist at all) are also strings

It failing utterly is entirely expected. Nothing is the right kind of data.

> ```
> ['a','b','c'].forEach.apply((function(a,b){return b;}),['a','b','c'])
> ```

This time:

- the `this` value (which should be an array) is a function
- and the arguments have the same problems as last time

---

You haven't said what you are trying to achieve, but you might be looking for something like this:

```js
function log_current_value (current_value) {
    console.log(current_value);
};
Array.prototype.forEach.apply(['a','b','c'], [log_current_value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `apply` you need to pass an array of arguments, i.e: `[fn]`:

```
['a','b','c'], [fn] <---- Callback function within an array.
 ^               
 |__ Array (First param).
```

```js
function fn(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

Array.prototype.forEach.apply(['a','b','c'], [fn]);
```

## Resource

- [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: No. The `this` value needs to be the array to loop over and not `null`. The first (and only) item in the array that is the second argument to `apply` needs to be the function. *Your live demo throws an error!!*

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, in firefox no.  I'm going to check.

Comment: The arguments to `.forEach.apply` should be `[], []`, not `[[], ]`

Comment: @ScottMarcus it's weird in firefox works.  I need to check the documentation.

Comment: `func.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, but why works passing `null` and `[[....], fn]` in FF.  I will find why works in FF.

Comment: Good question. For me, I'd rather know what works everywhere than chase down quirky behaviors. Work with the standards and a standards-compliant user agent will do the right thing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are passing `null` as the first argument to **[`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)** when you should be passing the array you want `.forEach()` to operate on.

Then, **[`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** requires that a callback function be supplied to it that will be called for each array item and the `.apply()` method requires that you pass any additional arguments in an array as well. A typical `.forEach()` invocation looks like this:

```
[...].forEach(function(value, index, array) { ...callback code...});
```

So that entire function argument needs to also be supplied to `.apply()`.

`.apply()` is supposed to be passed `(thisArg, [ arg, arg, arg, ...])` with the second argument being an array of arguments that the function being applied requires.

So, here's a breakdown of what you are seeing, why and the correct syntax:

```js
// The following fails with an error of: "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"
// because .forEach is a member of Array.prototype
//Array.forEach.apply(null,['a','b','c'])

// The following fails with an error of: "Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined"
// because .forEach is being passed null when it should be passed the array that it needs
// to enumerate:
//Array.prototype.forEach.apply(null,['a','b','c'])

// Pass the array to enumerate and an array of any arguments that .forEach() requires:
Array.prototype.forEach.apply(['a','b','c'], [ function(v,i,a){ console.log(v); } ]);
```